# how to increase a VirtualBox VM's hdd without a vdi file

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running VirtualBox v5.1.22. I already checked these two links: [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/2678/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-virtualbox-disk-image) and [two](https://superuser.com/questions/305462/how-to-increase-a-virtualbox-disk-size)

However, both of those mention .vdi files, which I do not seem to have. If I go to `C:\Users\[USER]\VirtualBox VMs\X_VM\` I see:

- X.vbox
- X-disk1.vmdk
- X.vbox-prev
- logs folder

Might be important to note: The VM was imported from an .ova file. Which I still have access to.

So with that said, does anyone know how I can increase the hdd my VM can use? Even if I don't seem to have a .vdi file.

Comment: As should be apparent by the file sizes the `.vmdk` file your "storage file" for that VM. You probably could convert it. [How to resize a VirtualBox vmdk file on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659005/how-to-resize-a-virtualbox-vmdk-file)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to vdi file:

```
VBoxManage clonehd "source.vmdk" "cloned.vdi" --format vdi
VBoxManage modifyhd "cloned.vdi" --resize 51200
```

Now you can follow the links you already checked, if you want you can convert it again into vmdk file:

```
VBoxManage clonehd "cloned.vdi" "resized.vmdk" --format vmdk
```

BTW, you must see that you're making a clone so you need to have enough free space to make the clone.